# aggregate column of nvarchar2 and obtain result in nvarchar2 too

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I need to create a view with an aggregate column of `nvarchar2(4000)` in Oracle 11g.

What I have:

`Table1` with every column of type `nvarchar2(4000)`:

```
Col_Name   txt_value
X                   a
X                   b
X                   c
Y                   a
Y                   c
```

The result should be a view like this with both columns of type `nvarchar2(4000)`:

```
Col_Name   txt_value
X                   a;b;c
Y                   a;c
```

I have tried with:

```
CREATE VIEW dict (col_Name, txt_value) AS 
SELECT col_Name, LISTAGG (txt_value,';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY txt_value)
FROM table1
GROUP BY col_Name
```

The only  problem is that `LISTAGG()` is converting the result in a column of type `varchar2(4000)` bit I need `nvarchar2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) describes:

> The return data type is RAW if the measure column is RAW; otherwise
>   the return value is VARCHAR2.

So unless you pass the column as `RAW`, the result will be `VARCHAR2`, and that is not good enough, because that means data loss during conversion.

`LISTAGG` works with `VARCHAR2` or `RAW`, so to simply put it, you need to convert everything to `RAW`, then convert the result back to `NVARCHAR2`.

Below is an example:

```
SQL> select parameter, value from nls_database_parameters where parameter like '%CHARACTERSET';

PARAMETER                      VALUE
------------------------------ ------------------------------
NLS_CHARACTERSET               EE8ISO8859P2
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET         AL16UTF16
```

My default characterset does not support the `€` sign.

```
SQL> create table t1 (id number, c1 varchar2(20), c2 nvarchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into t1 values (1, 'A', 'A');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t1 values (2,  NCHR(8364),  NCHR(8364));

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from t1;

        ID C1 C2
---------- -- --
         1 A  A
         2 ?  €
```

As you can see, i get a `?` instead of it using `VARCHAR2`.

If I simply try to use `LISTAGG` on the `NVARCHAR2` column, data will be lost during conversion:

```
select
  listagg(c2, ',') within group (order by id) as list1
from t1;

LIST1
----------
 A, Ź
```

If I try to cast the result, still not good enough, as data was lost during the conversion to `VARCHAR2`:

```
select
  cast(listagg(c2, ',') within group (order by id) as nvarchar2(20)) as list2
from t1;

LIST2
----------
 A, Ź
```

The remaining option is, to convert to `RAW`:

```
select
  utl_raw.cast_to_nvarchar2(listagg(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(c2), utl_raw.cast_to_raw(',')) within group (order by id)) as list3
from t1;

LIST3
----------
AⰠ
```

Converting a `VARCHAR2` delimiter will mess up the data, I need to specify the delimiter also in `NVARCHAR2`, so instead of `','`, I have to use `N','`:

```
select
  utl_raw.cast_to_nvarchar2(listagg(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(c2), utl_raw.cast_to_raw(N',')) within group (order by id)) as list4
from t1;

LIST4
----------
A,€
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `TO_CHAR()` function on the nvarchar field:

```
SELECT col_Name, LISTAGG (TO_CHAR(txt_value),';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY txt_value)
FROM table1
GROUP BY col_Name
```

More info: https://albert-kuo.blogspot.com/2015/08/oracle-listagg-cannot-handle-nvarchar2.html